# Removal of the delay on the first posts queue

Tags: discussion, review, new-users

Today on Electrical Engineering I noticed that the 15 minute delay on first post reviews  has been removed. Checking Stack Overflow I noticed the same so presumably it's been changed network wide. I may have found one potential drawback; the second first post I reviewed this morning was the following answer:

> How to implement hysteresis on the high-side, P-Channel cutoff circuit? Thanks

With the delay in place I'd expect it to appear on the first post, late answer and low-quality queues at the same time. On smaller sites it's often apparent they are probably all the same post so I'd normally go to the low-quality queue first where I'd get the option to use the pre-canned "ask a new question" comment and recommended deletion.

In this case after I flagged the answer it was quickly handled by a moderator but I have seen similar posts deleted in the past by six users with under 20k. I assume in this case I wouldn't have been able to review it later on another queue so I'd never get the chance to recommend a deletion? Not a hugely big deal but on smaller sites the extra vote can make a difference to the time they hang around.

Anyway I thought this was worth bringing up for discussion while the new triage system is being discussed as a potential drawback on smaller sites of removing the delay. Perhaps a simple solution would be to allow the same user that has reviewed a first post to later review it on the low-quality queue later either because it was placed there automatically or by a flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, there's nothing stopping you from reviewing the same post in multiple queues (in practice, some *actions* may prevent you from doing so - if you've already voted to close a post in First Posts or Low Quality, you're probably not gonna see it in Close review, and the same goes for some flags).

We're still discussing [more extensive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236537/lets-have-an-explicit-triage-system-for-questions-from-new-users) changes to First Posts, but in the mean time it's probably worth thinking about it as your *first* chance to send a given post in the right direction... but not necessarily your last.

Even very small sites suffer when low-quality posts hang around for a long time on the front page. Indeed, I've heard plenty of complaints along these lines from EE and other sites of similar size. The more we can do to send new questions in the right direction as soon as possible, the better.