# Remove the extra 15-minute delay for late answers entering the review queue

Tags: feature-request, review, late-answers

On one of the sites where I participate, brand new users often answer an old question for their first post.  That post appears within a few minutes in the "first post" queue, but nothing shows up in the "late answers" queue.  Then, about 15 minutes later, it appears in the late answers queue as well.

The difference in behavior seems to be associated with a 2014 change that was applied to first posts but not late answers, so I'm proposing that we treat them the same way and **remove the extra 15-minute delay for late answers**.

[Both queues used to have a 15-minute delay](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220420/300411):

> A post must meet the requirements for review for at least 15 minutes before it actually enters a review queue. For first posts and late answers, the post needs to have existed for at least 15 minutes before it becomes eligible.

In mid-2014, the [15-minute delay was removed for the first posts queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236549/300411), but not late answers. But Shog9's parting line seems like it could apply to late answers just as easily as new questions:

> The more we can do to send new questions in the right direction as soon as possible, the better.

The 15-minute delay on late answers can give an incentive to *leave new answers alone* until they reach the late answers queue, since review badges are more difficult to attain in the late answers queue than in first posts.

Put simply, my feature request is: **Treat late answers like first posts – eliminate the extra 15-minute delay associated with late answers entering the review queue.**

---

<sup>**Duplicate?** I found a question that might at first glance appear to be a duplicate – [Why are late answers not added instantly to review queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157577/300411) – but it focuses on "why do very old questions appear in the queue" and was closed as a duplicate of a question asking exactly that.  Asking this as a new question seemed preferable to editing that two-year-old post and trying to get it reopened.</sup>